How to decrease Gnome Boxes VM "screen" resolution and scale up the display
This is the opposite problem to most previous post I found.
I have a laptop with a fairly high resolution (3,XXX x 2,XXX) but small screen (13 inches). When I run a VM through GNOME Boxes, the SPICE driver automatically scale the screen size of the guest OS to fit the window size. However, since I want to run a pure TTY environment, the text is so small that they are barely readable.
With virt-manager, I have option to not scale the virtual screen to the window, but to keep a lower resolution and upscale to the large window size. The result is much, much more readable than otherwise.
Is there a way to setup GNOME Boxes to run VM the same?
